# How do I store the selected value of a UIPickerView and display it in a label in a different ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have just started learning swift, I don't know much so I'm sorry if I don't understand things. I am creating a contacts app. In the AddViewController (this is the add contact page), I have 4 UIPickerView's. I would like to save the selected values. Once the contact is created I can click into the contact to show the DetailViewController, this allows me to see the contact details. This is where I need to show the selected values of the UIPickerViews as labels. I also want to then be able to click an edit button and it take me back to the AddViewController to edit the details. I will need to display the selected values for the pickers in the UIPickerViews.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data through a segue from one view controller to another.

Set up the segue on the storyboard then

```
    if segue.identifier == "AddViewSegue"{
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
            let addVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddViewController") as! AddViewController
            addVC.pickerOneResult = pickerOneResult
        }
    }
```

So you store your picker result in a var pickerOneResult, and have a matching var in the other viewcontroller

Comment: When I select a value in a picker it doesn't display it in the picker and it also crashes when i select a value in more than one picker and takes me to the AppDelegate.swift file saying "Thread1: signal SIGABRT"

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have selected content `ABC` from your UIPickerView. 
And if you want to preselect the same in UIPickerView on some launch. 
You can do the following:

`1` From the array, you find the index of selected row.

`2` And apply the same using this function below

```
pickerView.selectRow(<THIS IS YOUR INDEX>, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```